# How to get the list of offline users in ejabberd MUC?

Tags: ejabberd, offline-mode

I am building a chat app (native - android and ios) using ejabberd 20.04. I want to send a offline user notification when a user gets a message whether one to one chat or MUC.  I see a lot of custom libraries on git and all of them work for one to one chat. When it is MUC, I need to get offline user list like this.

```
{
    "from": "string",
    "messageId": "string",
    "to (MUC name group or jID in 1 to 1": "string",
    "vhost": "string",
    "offline_list": "[jID1, jID2, jID3]"
}
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: MUC is presence-driven and only works with connected and online participants. There are a couple of workarounds to make MUC work with offline people but those are workarounds (registering with the room). There is an alternative in the form of XEP-0369 (MIX), which alleviate this issue and works based on registration with the room (and users can opt-in to receive presence information) but it's not widely adopted (ejabberd doesn't support it)

Answer (score 0):

If the user is offline, he is not occupant in the room, then what you ask makes no sense.